# How to verify emails on Laravel 5.7 Multiple Guards?

Tags: laravel

I am using multiple guards and want to use Laravel inbuilt system for sending verification emails. I am doing following

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'frontEnd' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],

    ...
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Customer::class,
    ],

    ...
],
```

In the User Model and Customer Model, I am using MustVerifyEmail. Both Model has email_verified_at column. When I am creating a user and when that user tries to login he redirects to email/verify the route. Email does not trigger at the time of creating a User.

For some reasons I am not using Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); insted i put

```
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');

Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

On route/web.php file

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tarasovych Please look at the edited question.

Comment: *"Email does not trigger"* - email isn't being sent or what?

Comment: Why do you want to verify email multiple times in the first place? Email verification is just to test if the email used is valid/invalid that's it. So just go ahead with auth routes. The verification process is independent of guards

Comment: Yes, the verification email was not sent at the time of customer registration. I am using MustVerifyEmail on the Customer model.